# Sending an email via Outlook

Tags: python, python-2.x, outlook

I have a function which sends an email via outlook when given text, a subject, and recipients shown below:

```
def __Emailer(text, subject, recipient, auto=True):
    import win32com.client as win32   

    outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    if type(recipient) == type([]):
        for name in recipient:
            mail.Recipients.Add(name)
    else:
        mail.To = recipients
    mail.Subject = subject
    mail.HtmlBody = text
    if auto:
        mail.send
    else:
        mail.Display(True)
```

Now, I know that type comparisons in Python are *strongly discouraged*, but I can't think of a better way to do this.  I want it to send to multiple addresses if `recipient` is a list using the `mail.Recipients.Add(name)`, and `mail.To` if there is only one name (not given as a list).  How can I accomplish this without using nasty type comparisons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python, it is part of the mentality to check for behavior rather than for exact type.

Your method doesn't even need `recipients` to be a list—it can be any iterable (e.g. a set) so it can be used in the `for` loop. Strings, however, are also iterable, so you need to tell *them* apart.

One way to check if something is a string is to [look for a string-specific method, such as `strip`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1835259/458193).

```
def __Emailer(text, subject, recipients, auto=True):
    import win32com.client as win32   

    outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)

    if hasattr(recipients, 'strip'):
        recipients = [recipients]

    for recipient in recipients:
        mail.Recipients.Add(recipient)

    mail.Subject = subject
    mail.HtmlBody = text

    if auto:
        mail.send
    else:
        mail.Display(True)
```

Comment: That's beautiful. I thought of doing something like this with ```try...except```, but I'd actually have to execute code to do that, this is much better!

Comment: `mail.Recipients.Add(recipient)` should fail if you try to add a list.  If so, you could duck type off that behavior.  This is more of design problem of the calling function or the function being called.

Comment: @dansalmo But why would `recipient` be a list? It would only be the case if you passed a nested list to `recipients`.

Comment: Yes, Just pass what is received, then if `mail.Recipients.Add(recipient)` is a list, it will fail, then you can iterate over it.  I meant to comment on the original question above, where `recipient` might be a list or string.

Comment: Ah, I got it! I'm not feeling sure about duck type something outside of Python's bounds though (`Add` is from Outlook COM API).

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes type checking makes for more readable code than duck typing, and this is probably one of those cases. What you shouldn't do is compare the types the way you are doing, it is better to use `isinstance` instead. You could check directly for the input being a string as:

```
if isinstance(recipient, str):
    mail.To = recipients
else:
    for name in recipient:
        mail.Recipients.Add(name)
```

You may also want to look at the [ABCs (Abstract Base Classes) in the `collections` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections-abstract-base-classes), which provide a convenient way to check for certain general attributes in an object.